# What is the corresponding rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have the following ActiveRecord migration:

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end

    change_table :projects do |t|
      t.references :subjects
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :subjects
    remove_column :projects, :subjects_id #defeats the purpose of having references
  end
end
```

I actually like the `references` style. Unfortunately I could not find the rollback equivalent of `references` in the `self.down` section. If I write `remove_column :projects, :subjects_id` I can as well write `t.integer :subjects_id`, which would make it safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called [remove_references](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#M000212).

```
t.remove_references :subjects
```

Be careful! Rails uses singular by convention, should be:

```
def self.up
  create_table :subjects do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.timestamps
  end

  change_table :projects do |t|
    t.references :subject
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_table :subjects
  change_table :projects do |t|
    t.remove_references :subject
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'm officially unable to read the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-remove_references